# Issues in creating an SVM model using Python

Tags: python, svm, object-detection

This is how i have trained for object detection in `opencv-python`

```
  def svmTrain(self):
    print "CCC\n"
    points=[]
    labels=[]
    f=open('fv2.txt', 'rb')
    objs = []
    while 1:
        try:
            objs.append(cPickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
    for i in range(0,len(objs)):
        labels.append(int(objs[i][0][0]))
        fv=objs[i][1][0]
        points.append(fv)
    print "DDD\n"   
    print labels
    svmpoints=np.array(points,dtype=np.float32)
    svmlabels=np.array(labels,dtype=np.float32)
            print "EEE\n"
    model = cv2.SVM(svmpoints,svmlabels)
            print "FFF\n"
    model.save("model.xml")
            print "The end\n"
```

But it gives an error will exection

> TypeError : responses data type =18 is not supported

Please help me to find a solution how to make the `SVM model` in python